# initializing two different random variables at the same time

Tags: variables, random

I am writing a script using 'java.util.Random' and I am trying to initialize two random variables for the same println but it only works if I comment out one of the variables. Here is the code where my problem is:

```
Random a = new Random();
        date = a.nextInt(29) + 1;
        year = a.nextInt(2019 - 2044)+ 1;

        System.out.println("The best day of your life will be on " + month +       " " + date + ","+ " " + year + ".....give or take.\n");
        System.out.println("Which date of the month do you believe is your   luckiest?");
```

I can't figure out how to initialize 'date' and 'year' at the same time.
  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you share the output you're getting and the output you're trying to get?

Comment: I think the problem starts below Random a = new Random();  The two lines where I am trying to initialize the two random variables: date and year. There seems to be a problem with initializing two variables at once. See if I comment out one of the variables then it will work fine but two randoms will return nothing.